# Handle HEIF images from Java

Tags: java, api, heif

I want my app to be able to handle .heic images. However, this has been far from easy. I have tried using this nokia lib: https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/

but no luck whatsoever. Even though I can load the image as a HEIF and save it somewhere else that's the extent of what I can do. I can't even extract metadata let alone get the image or convert it to another format. I've tested it using several images given by the creators of the lib so it's not a problem of the particular image I'm using.

Is there a way to be able to manipulate HEIF images in Java? I've seen some paid APIs but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I notice a non-trivial step in the build instructions, "you need to have the HEIF JNI library built in the earlier step (heifjni.dll or heifjni.so) in the Java library search path.". Did you correctly handle that?

Comment: Yes, and before I did it would raise an error every time I tried to load a heic image. Now I get no errors, just not any information either

Comment: I just confirmed that the lib isn't missing anything or I'm loading my heic image incorrectly, cause I can get the dimensions of the img by doing heif.getPrimaryImage().getSize(). However, again, I can't get any other useful information out of the image